# For loop running only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with a small issue, here I have more than 10 table rows, but my code is executing only once. Here is my code. Please help me on this

```
var rowlength = $("#totalLostProductGrid tbody tr ").length;

for(var i=1;i<=rowlength;i++){


    var startDateVal = $("#lpostartDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    var endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    var lostProductValue = $("#lostProductionStartToEnd_"+i).val();
    var realEndDateVal = $("#eEndTime").val().split(/-|\s|:/);

    var FLNominalvalue = $("#idNominalPower").text();
    var idEstimatedLostProdVal = $("#idEstimatedLostProd").val();


    var durationTime = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

    var actualVal = durationTime * lostProductValue;

    alert(actualVal);

    if(actualVal  < FLNominalvalue){
        alert("success");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("invalid case");
        return false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to not **return false** if ok

```
$("#totalLostProductGrid tbody tr").each(function(i) {
  i++; // assuming your fields start at 1
  var startDateVal = $("#lpostartDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      lostProductValue = $("#lostProductionStartToEnd_"+i).val(),
      realEndDateVal = $("#eEndTime").val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      FLNominalvalue = $("#idNominalPower").text(),
      idEstimatedLostProdVal = $("#idEstimatedLostProd").val(),
      durationTime = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

  var actualVal = durationTime * lostProductValue;

  console.log(actualVal);

  if(actualVal  < FLNominalvalue){
    console.log(i+":success");
  }else{
    alert("row #"+i+" contains an invalid case");
    return false;
  }
});
```

or ONLY return false if NOT ok:

```
$("#totalLostProductGrid tbody tr").each(function(i) {
  i++; // assuming your fields start at 1
  var startDateVal = $("#lpostartDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_"+i).val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      lostProductValue = $("#lostProductionStartToEnd_"+i).val(),
      realEndDateVal = $("#eEndTime").val().split(/-|\s|:/),
      FLNominalvalue = $("#idNominalPower").text(),
      idEstimatedLostProdVal = $("#idEstimatedLostProd").val(),
      durationTime = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

  var actualVal = durationTime * lostProductValue;
  if(actualVal >= FLNominalvalue){
    alert("row #"+i+" contains an invalid case");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, that's a foreach... So you can return.

Comment: I mean you are specifically not returning true. You could return true from the functions, as the OP has done.

Comment: I know. That is the intended behaviour, is it not? But it might be a bit confusing for the OP to find the `return true;` missing. I would recommend adding that but saying that it is optional, and also saying that the `return false` exits from the foreach, as you have commented everything else.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the loop you're returning from it, essentially exiting it.

Also, are you sure you intend to start at index 1 instead of 0? (var i=0)

Comment: He likely has lpostartDate_1 as the first field

Answer (score 0):

```
if(actualVal  < FLNominalvalue){
        alert("success");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("invalid case");
        return false;
        }
```

this means whatever the result is it will return false, which will end foreach

Comment: maybe there's error something like var undefined in your script